# How to skip different prompts in BASH

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm looking to a way to automate a script execution, which has 5 prompts: `4xYES` and `1*NO`.
The prompts are constantly located on the same place:

> yes | yes | yes | no | yes

Something like in the example below (based on 3 prompts):

```
#!/bin/bash

read -r -p "Ready to proceed? [yes/no]: " input

if [[ "$input" = "yes" ]]
 then
  read -r -p "Or maybe abort? [yes/no]: " answer
   if [[ "$answer" = "no" ]]
    then
     read -r -p "So... proceed? [yes/no]: " response
      if [[ "$response" = "yes" ]]
       then echo "NICE JOB!!!"
      fi
   fi
fi
```

Obviously, passing a single "yes" or "no" via the pipe to this script will no work, as the expected responses are different. Not aware whether there is a way to pass multiple params via the pipe.

I thought to create an array `PROMPT=(yes no yes)`, and pass `$i` via the pipe to the script, but this will not work as well, and i do not need cyclic script execution for each `$i`.

Is there any way to pass different answers to the prompt, if their places are constant?

Comment: You mentioned that you can not place the input in pipe (or a file ?). Is there a reason for that ? read will usually take input from a file, if you redirect the input (script < file).

Comment: @dash-o: I'm aware only about a simple redirect, like `yes |./script`. Is there a way to pass an ordered series of responses via the pipe??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `printf` and a pipe

```
printf '%s\n' yes yes yes no yes | ./script.sh
```

or input redirection and a process substitution

```
./script.sh < <(printf '%s\n' yes yes yes no yes)
```

or a here-string

```
./script.sh <<<$'yes\nyes\nyes\nno\nyes'
```

or a here-document

```
./script.sh <<'EOF'
yes
yes
yes
no
yes
EOF
```

Comment: Prefer the pipe or here document for portability. I don't seen any particular benefit for the process substitution over the other options here.

Answer (score 0):

By 'simulating' a 'enter' with a new line

Something like:

```
echo "yes\nno\nyes" | bash myscript.sh
```

Pass your bash script

Comment: `printf` is far better, as you don't have to worry about compile-time or run-time settings that determine whether `echo` will actually expand `\n` to a newline.